# streaming multiprocessor number

Tags: cuda, gpu

how do I know how many streaming multiprocessors(SM) I have on my GTS 250?

Comment: Read the GPU specs available on NVIDIA's website.

Answer (score 5):

You can Download the SDK and run  deviceQuery

CUDASDK_32/C/bin/linux/release/deviceQuery

```
Device 0: "Tesla S2050"
  CUDA Driver Version:                           3.10
  CUDA Runtime Version:                          3.10
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2817982464 bytes
```

---

### And see this line:

```
 Multiprocessors x Cores/MP = Cores:  14 (MP) x 32 (Cores/MP) = 448 (Cores)
```

---

```
 Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Clock rate:                                    1.15 GHz
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated:                                    No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Compute mode:                                  Default (multiple host threads can use this device simultaneously)
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                Yes

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 3.10, CUDA Runtime Version = 3.10, NumDevs = 1, Device = Tesla S2050
```

Answer (score 1):

The GTS 250 has 16 SMs and 8 cores per SM for a total of 128 CUDA cores.  [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_200_Series) has core counts for all GeForce devices.  For GT200 series processors dividing the number of cores by 8 gives you the number of SMs.

Comment: That wikipedia page is helpful. But I cannot find where in there it says that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 12-year-old post, however, recently I had similar confusion finding the `sm_` of my GPU.

For future reference, I found if you run the `__nvcc_device_query.exe` (for windows), a similar should be also for Linux under CUDA installed directory, and in `bin` folder, you will get the number.