# How to get the total gpu thread counts?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu

I found one related [answer](https://superuser.com/a/198309/1658455), but I have some questions about it.

I use the GTX 1650 and related infos are (I have dropped some unrelated infos):

```bash
$ /opt/cuda/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery
Device 0: "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650"
  (14) Multiprocessors, ( 64) CUDA Cores/MP:     896 CUDA Cores
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
```

Q: Then how can `x` in "grid size" be larger than `1024*14` which is weird? `(2147483647,1,1)` may exceed thread counts what the GPU can offer (i.e. `1024*14`).

And it is the same case for `y,z` in the "grid size".

Comment: why would `Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor (1024)` x `Multiprocessors (14)` be significant to the value of `x`? And why is `y` and `z` not equally confusing to you? they are both greater than 1024x14

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I will change my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia: Thread Block (CUDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_block_(CUDA_programming)):

> Multiple blocks are combined to form a grid. All the blocks in the same grid contain the same number of threads. **The number of threads in a block is limited, but grids can be used for computations that require a large number of thread blocks to operate in parallel and to use all available multiprocessors**.

Also

> Unlike the maximum threads per block, there is not a blocks per grid limit distinct from the maximum grid dimensions.

So grids are essentially a construct that holds all the blocks available to be executed, they do not correlate to the number of thread blocks available within the processor.

Which is common in computing.

You often have tasks that can be broken down into work units and have many more work units than threads available. Then you have to simply set up a scheduler that puts a new work block into the processor block when another block finishes.

This can still be handled by the hardware. There's nothing stopping a hardware scheduler from knowing how to handle a linked list of objects that says "when one finishes then grab the next from this list".